# How to add an address to an organization's Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I can't figure out how to add an address to my church's Facebook page. I read through a few different websites but no one seems to have the same problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/197254963682414):

> **How do I add an address to my Page?**
>
> To add an address to your Page, your Page's category must be **Companies & Organizations** or **Local Businesses**. Keep in mind that you can only add one address. To add an address:
>
> 1. Click **About** below your Page's cover photo
> 2. Click **Page Info** in the left column
> 3. Click to edit the **Address** section
> 4. Add your address and click **Save Changes**

**Note:** You must have an Admin role on the page to edit or make any changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your Church's Facebook Page but it requires that you have **Administrator Privileges** to that Page.

1. Click About below your Page's cover photo
2. Click Page Info in the left column
3. Click to edit the Address section
4. Add your address and click Save Changes